# Is it good practice to shuffle character set before they are picked randomly

Tags: java, string, random

To generate a N-length String randomly, almost all of the examples I have seen in here used this either digits before the alphabet or alphabet before the digits:

`String alphanumeric = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"`

For this list, index of each character is known beforehand (For example, 'A' at index 0, 'B' at index 1, ...) even though we pick a random integer to find the element by index number in alphanumeric String.

I wonder is it a good practice to shuffle alphanumeric characters before we pick elements randomly in the iteration?

Thus, characters will be randomly distributed (not ordered), no one can guess the sequence.

Comment: As long as you're not keeping the indexes you pick, there's no benefit. The string isn't more random or less predictable if you shuffle first.

Comment: So what if the indexes are known? This can be a problem if someone can predict the next number generated by your random generator, and in this case you have more serious problem.

Comment: Shuffling is the best solution if you are sampling without replacement. If you are doing sampling with replacement, it's just an extra step that doesn't give you benefit.

Comment: one reason to shuffle is to avoid repetitions, that is, once one element is taken it is removed

Comment: @Chaosfire If the RNG is predictable, so is the shuffle, so pre-shuffling won't give any benefit to sampling w/ replacement.

Comment: I assume that random number generator is not predictable, for example we are using ```SecureRandom```.

Comment: However, we know which letter is at which index (location).

Comment: Are you allowing letters to be sampled more than once, i.e., you permit duplicates? Sampling with or without replacement are two different endeavors.

Comment: I did not understand very well. Do you mean a letter is used more than one in the generated sequence? for example **A9FGA** 'A' is used two times.

Comment: @pjs I don't really get your point. Am I not saying the same? There is no benefit in shuffling.

Comment: Yes, **A9FGA** would be an example of sampling with replacement (of the 'A').

Comment: yes, why not? :) a letter might be used more than once.

Comment: @Chaosfire I'm saying that if you are doing sampling with replacement, there is no benefit to shuffling, it's just an extra layer of work. If you are doing sampling without replacement, shuffling and iterating through the shuffled list is the optimal solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. That's not how randomness works. You're effectively proposing:

"If shuffling this pack of cards and then drawing a card from it is really random, imagine how much more random it becomes if I shuffle **twice**!".

That is only true if your shuffle skills suck. There are only two options:

1. Given the actual ordering of the cards after your shuffle, I can make guesstimates about what the ordering was *before* you started shuffling, and those guesstimates are better than random odds ('random odds' = I can guess the top card was an jack of spades. By pure happenstance I'd be right once every 52 such guesses, because a standard pack of cards has 52 cards in it. If my guesswork based on inspecting the deck after you shuffle give me *better than* 1/52 odds, that's what we're talking about here): Then **you suck at shuffling**. The fix is to be better.
2. There is absolutely nothing meaningful I can learn from inspecting the deck's order after you have shuffled - it says absolutely nothing about what order the cards where in before you did so. This means you are good at shuffling.

Given #2, there is literally zero point in shuffling again.

The same applies to your question. There are only 2 options:

1. The algorithm to pick an arbitrary value from the list of valid characters is proper.
2. It is not proper.

In case #1, there is point at all in randomizing the order of the symbols before picking randomly from it. In case #2, doing that may help, but, that's **not** what you should be doing. Instead, you should be fixing your 'pick randomly' algorithm!

Or possibly, you're in a scenario where the computer is not capable of randomizing, and hence, door #2 is what's happening, and that cannot be fixed. However, in such a circumstance, you also cannot shuffle the symbols in a random way either.

It doesn't matter which way you try to reason about this: **it is never correct to want to shuffle that list first**.

### So what's a proper algorithm?

```
String alphanumeric = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
char randomChar = alphanumeric.charAt(rnd.nextInt(alphanumeric.length());
```

Where `rnd` is an instance of `java.util.Random`. Depending on what's happening, you may want to create this instance with `new SecureRandom()`.

### I want to pick without replacement

If you want to ensure a picked character cannot be picked again, the usual way to do that, especially with so few items in the batch of stuff that can be picked, is to shuffle the batch of stuff, and then just pick off the top. The correct way to do that:

```
Random rnd = new SecureRandom();

// first put all elements in a list
List<Character> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < alphanumeric.length(); i++) {
  list.add(alphanumeric.charAt(i);
}

// then shuffle it
Collections.shuffle(list, rnd);

// then just pick off the top:

char firstPassChar = list.get(0);
char secondPassChar = list.get(1);
// and so on
```

Again, zero point in picking randomly from this shuffled list. It's shuffled. The thing at position 0 is as random as the thing at -randomly chosen position- would be. You can't turn '100% random' into something that is even more random.

Comment: At its core, my question is can we reach full randomness from something that is being ordered? Working on an ordered collection impacts negatively on it being fully random? From your answer, especially the last part, we make something random by using an efficient algorithm, no need to make it more random initially. Thanks.

Comment: _At its core, my question is can we reach full randomness from something that is being ordered?_ - you're going to have to define what you mean precisely, but _generally_ - yes. Certainly, you can't reach 'more' full randomness by doing the act you suggest. Either you don't have a sufficiently reliable source of randomness in which case there's nothing you can do, or, you do, and picking randomly is as good as its going to get, and shuffling the list isn't going to add anything.

Comment: @Eric As an analogy, if you need five random numbers, you can visit a casino where you watch only a single roulette wheel produce five numbers in succession. Moving around to watch one spin of each of five randomly-selected different roulette wheels does *not* give you more randomness (assuming the roulette wheel is perfectly balanced).